# Grand Central Dispatch Multiple DispatchGroups

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I have three async calls. One returns data, and two return images from S3 using firebase. I have one background DispatchQueue, and three dispatch groups. I need a way for them to execute synchronously, but they don't! I have tried everything, and .notify executes immediately, which is wrong.

The output of this **is**: 
images done 
all is done 
group.notify is done 
getImages() is done

What I want to understand is why is imagesdone executed before group.notify is done? I need to execute the first group, then imagesGroup, then avaGroup.

I essentially have three async calls, and the 2nd/3rd may be multiple async calls. How can I wait for them to complete, then execute subsequent calls?

```
func loadFriendPhotos() {

    let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.queue",
                                        qos: .utility,
                                        target: nil)

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    let imageGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let avaGroup = DispatchGroup()
    typealias tempAlias = (username:String, imageURL: String, pathUrl:String)

    var tempAliasArray = [tempAlias]()
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()
    var avaImageArray = [UIImage]()

    group.enter()
    let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
        databaseRef.child("friendPhotos").child(globalUsername).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {

                let enumerator = snapshot.children
                var childrenCount = snapshot.childrenCount


                while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {

                    let name = rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String
                    let downloadURL = rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "downloadURL").value as! String
                    let uid = rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "uid").value as! String
                    let pathURL = rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "pathURL").value as! String
                    let downloadURLRef = storage.reference(forURL: downloadURL)

                    let newTempAlias = tempAlias(name, downloadURL, pathURL)
                    tempAliasArray.append(newTempAlias)
                }
                group.leave()
            }
        })
    }

    func getAvaImages() {
        for index in tempAliasArray{
            avaGroup.enter()
            let avaItem = DispatchWorkItem {
                let avaURLRef = storage.reference(forURL: index.1)
                avaURLRef.data(withMaxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024) { (data,error) in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        print("success!")
                        let picData = UIImage(data:data!)
                        avaImageArray.append(picData!)

                    } else {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    print("we left getAvaImages()")
                    avaGroup.leave()

                }
            }
            backgroundQueue.async(execute: avaItem)
        }
    }

    func getImages() {
        for index in tempAliasArray{
            imageGroup.enter()
            let imageItem = DispatchWorkItem {
                let downloadURLRef = storage.reference(forURL: index.1)
                downloadURLRef.data(withMaxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024) { (data,error) in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        let picData = UIImage(data:data!)
                        imageArray.append(picData!)
                    } else {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    print("we left getImages()")
                    imageGroup.leave()
                }
            }
            backgroundQueue.async(execute: imageItem)
        }
    }

    backgroundQueue.sync(execute: workItem)

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        print("group.notify is done")
        getImages()
    })
    imageGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        print("images done")
        getAvaImages()
    })
    avaGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        print("all is done")
    })
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `imageGroup.notify` at a point that there is nothing in `imageGroup`, so it immediately notifies. Similarly, `avaGroup` notifies immediately since it is empty at the point that you call it.

But I don't understand all the indirection and groups and three arrays. Why do you have to wait for all the images to download before you deal with each image? Why not just kick off the next step inside the original loop for just one element? Something like this:

```
var allTheResults = []

group.enter() // Enter once for the top-level
kickOffAsyncWithCompletion { resultList in

    for item in resultList {
        let resultThing = doSomeStuffToSetupNextLevel()

        group.enter() // Enter once per thing we iterate over

        kickOffNestedAsync(with: resultThing, completion: { result in
            let finalResult = computeFinalResult(fromResult: result)
            allTheResults.append(finalResult)
            group.leave() // leave once per thing we iterate over
        })
    }
    group.leave() // leave once for the top level
}

group.notify { doThing(withFinalResults: allTheResults) }
```

If you want to coordinate the endpoint of set of operations, you want all those operations to be working with the same group, not separate groups per operation.

Comment: hi @rob-napir, are both group.enter() calls to the same dispatchGroup?

Comment: Broader question, if you are making multiple async calls do you use the same group, or if there was a kickoffAsyncWithCompletion2 at same level as kickOffAsyncWithCompletion would it be a different group

Comment: The probelm Im experiencing is group1 automatically exits, triggering group1.notify, which shouldnt happen. This doesnt happen and does trigger after when NOT nesting group.enter()'s

Comment: A group notifies whenever the number of leaves equals the number of enters. This has nothing to do with how the code is structured, nested, or the order of operations. It is a simple reference counting system. If you ever allow leaves to equal enters, then the group is done. Things that you want to track together and wait on together, enter and leave the same group. The key point is that groups know nothing about async or callbacks or anything. They just enter and leave. Make sure those happen when you want them to happen.